# Passing data from customize-controls.js to the customize-preview.js

Tags: theme-customizer

Is this the correct way to pass data from customize-controls.js to customize-preview.js?

```
( function( api ) {

api.controlConstructor['typography'] = api.Control.extend( {
    ready: function() {
        var control = this;

        function addGoogleFont(fontName) {
                var font = control.params.ogf_fonts[fontName];
                var weights = $.map(font.variants, function(value, key) {
                  return key;
                });
                var weightsURL = weights.join(',');
                var fontURL = font.family.replace(' ','+') + ':' + weightsURL;
                wp.customize.previewer.send( 'olympusFontURL', "<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=" + fontURL + "' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>" );
        }

        control.container.on( 'change', '.typography-font-family select',
            function() {
                var value = jQuery( this ).val();
                control.settings['family'].set( value );
                if( value != 'default' ) {

                    addGoogleFont( value );

                    var font = control.params.ogf_fonts[value];
                    var weightsSelect = jQuery( '.typography-font-weight select' );
                    var newWeights = font.variants;
                    weightsSelect.empty();
                    $.each( newWeights, function( key, val ) {
                        weightsSelect.append( $( "<option></option>" )
                             .attr( "value", key ).text( val ) );
                    });
                }
            }
        );

    }
} );

} )( wp.customize );
```

Also is this better than trying to `.append()` to the preview iframe  directly in customize-controls.js?

Here is customize-preview.js for anyone interested:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    wp.customize.bind( 'preview-ready', function() {
      wp.customize.preview.bind( 'olympusFontURL', function( url ) {
         console.log(url);
         $("head").append(url);
      } );
    } );

} ); // jQuery( document ).ready
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Customizer Message Passing

What follows are some snippets that show the required order of operations for getting the message-passing handshakes to work. In your example code, the control is sending the message on `change` so it's likely that this will not happen before the overall `ready` event and it should be ok.

### Pane → Preview

```
/* Pane, enqueue w/ customize-controls dependency at customize_controls_enqueue_scripts */
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {
  wp.customize.previewer.bind( 'ready', function() {
     wp.customize.previewer.send( 'greeting', 'Howdy, Preview!' );
  } );
} );

/* Preview, enqueue /w customize-preview dependency at wp_enqueue_scripts if is_customize_preview() */
wp.customize.bind( 'preview-ready', function() {
  wp.customize.preview.bind( 'greeting', function( message ) {
     console.info( Pane sent message:', message );
  } );
} );
```

### Preview → Pane

```
/* Preview, enqueue /w customize-preview dependency at wp_enqueue_scripts if is_customize_preview() */
wp.customize.bind( 'preview-ready', function() {
  wp.customize.preview.bind( 'active', function() {
     wp.customize.preview.send( 'greeting', 'Howdy, Pane!' );
  } );
} );

/* Pane, enqueue w/ customize-controls dependency at customize_controls_enqueue_scripts */
wp.customize.bind( 'ready', function() {
  wp.customize.previewer.bind( 'greeting', function( message ) {
     console.info( 'Preview sent greeting:', message );
  } );
} );
```

## Suggestion

Instead of adding a `change` event listener for the `select` element via jQuery,  the `select` element should rather be linked with a setting which you listen to instead. So your `ready` method should really look more like this:

```
this.setting.bind( function( newFont ) {
    if ( 'default' !== newFont ) {
        addGoogleFont( newFont );
    }
} );
```

But this `addGoogleFont` is passing the entire `link` tag to the preview, in addition to the setting change being sent. Wouldn't it be better to move all of the `addGoogleFont` logic into the preview itself? For example:

```
wp.customize( fontSettingId, function( setting ) {
    setting.bind( function( newFont ) {
        if ( 'default' !== newFont ) {
            addGoogleFont( newFont );
        }
    } );
} )
```

So then you just listen to the change to the font setting change in the preview, then construct the `link` tag to update in the preview there.

Comment: Thanks Weston! The typography control is used three times, so my understanding is that if I bind it to the select in customize-controls.js I only have to write that code once. If I moved that to preview.js, I would need to add it to the bind code for each setting, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.