# Refresh Customize Section (not preview)

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

I am building controls (a) that are generated using a value from a control (b) in another section.

However, unless the full customize page is refreshed then then there doesn’t seem to be a way to update (a) when (b) changes. Is there a solution for this use-case?

Comment: very similar to my question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293902/can-i-partial-refresh-a-customizer-control

Answer (score 1):

It depends what "update" means.

If you want just to hide or show the control, (like how WordPress sidebar area is appearing and disappearing when the sidebar is present or not) then you can use the `active_callback` parameter of the [customize_control](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_control) like [this](https://blog.josemcastaneda.com/2015/07/23/using-active-callbacks-in-the-customizer).

**Edit**: Also, `active_callback` works on sections and panels too.

If you want the change the control's HTML structure, or text or anything else, then it requires advanced javascript knowledge, because you need to trigger javascript events from the previewer and catch them on the panel.
This [example comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/301080/26395) should be enough for this case.

Comment: The example question you linked was mine too, however it's a different use-case. What I'm essentially asking is if there is 'Selective Refresh' for sections/panels like there is for content in the previewer.

Comment: Yep, as far as I know, there is no selective refresh for sections/panels. This is why I'm saying that you need to build your own custom events in `preview-ready`.